# jQuery.show() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

See the page at: http://216.231.135.200/test/view.html

As you click 'Next', the next bar will first extend and then contract back, which is not the effect I want. Can anyone help me?

--Update:

> He means when the animation is done, the bottom part of the element
>   judders. He wants to prevent that. – lolwut

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: What do you WANT there to happen? Please clarify. And if possible make a [jsfiddle mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/), which is easier to edit and show as an example back to you too.

Comment: It's not contracting back for me. It shows the next line, then the next, etc.

Comment: He means when the animation is done, the bottom part of the element judders. He wants to prevent that.

Comment: @lolwut: Not sure what "judders" means, but it's just showing the next element and being still in IE8.0.6

Comment: @Jonathan M: In my explorer (I tested with both Firefox and Chrome) the height of the box will first appears to be larger and then contract back a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your .step_container class a fixed height.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to explicitly give all the `div.step-container` a height using css.

Comment: I was a little too late to give my answer ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Solved it with some css: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VLSc9/

```
.step-container {
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 21px; /*stops the jitter */
    max-height: 21px; /*stops the jitter*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `show()` try `slideDown()` maybe thats what you mean?

You can find a list of other animations/effects on the [jquery api documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Else please specify your expected behaviour.

It seems jQuery can't calculate correctly which height the new container needs to have, if you can specify a height for the container it should be fixed...